# filter dataset in Pandas based on a specific datetime column condition

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe with recorded dates and event dates, I use the following script to create a new dataframe with only rows where record and event dates match.

```
New_df =df1.loc[(df1['record_date'] == df1['event_date'])]
```

However I want to include rows from dataset where record dates are +- 1 day, 2 day, 3 days from event date including above code.
How can  do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you try this:

```
New_df =df1.loc[abs((df1['record_date'] - df1['event_date'])).dt.days <= 3] #get +- 3 days
```

Answer (score 1):

```
new_df = df.loc[df.record_date.sub(df.event_date).abs().le('3d')]
```

Comment: how is it different from the above solution?

Comment: It doesn't do an unnecessary transition from `datetime` to `int` via `.dt.days`~ And cleans up a the syntax quite a bit.

Comment: what if I want to change range 3 days to x days? what part do i change?

Comment: Then you could use `f'{x}d'` instead of `'3d'`

Comment: If you want to be explicit about it: `pd.Timedelta(x, unit='days')`